# How much clearance is necessary for duct cleaning?

Tags: cleaning, vent

I'm having my ducts cleaned tomorrow and I'm preparing for their arrival tonight. Despite all my research I'm unable to find how much room these cleaners typically need, and unfortunately it's too late to call them. How much clearance will the vent cleaners need to properly access my vents?

Answer (score 2):

Duct cleaners are likely to use long air and vacuum hoses connected to a large device in their vehicle or stationed outside your home. They'll just need access to stand or crouch outside each vent and manipulate those hoses as they insert and retract them. Furniture very close by may get bumped or scuffed and could make the work more difficult.

Do try to establish some way of inspecting their work, though. When I had my ducts done many years ago I didn't. Not long later I did a duct reconfiguration and found huge mats of dust and lint still laying in heaps in the primary duct. Since then I've considered duct cleaning a racket, but maybe other companies do better. See if you can verify the quality of the work.